# How to display "Properties" (of Types/Classes) window?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have been using 2 kinds of Properties facilities:

(1) Properties of a Project/Solution

(2) Properties of XAML stuff

This web page (scroll to the bottom) seems to indicate that there is a way to see properties of all classes. Boy! Can I use that! Currently, to see properties of types what I do is either press "dot" (IntelliSense) or go to the Microsoft MSDN site.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/savefiledialog

How can I summon the dialog depicted below?

[image]

Addition: When I right-click, this is what is shown:

[image]

The **Alt-Enter** opens the "Properties" dialog, but it is empty. Maybe I have a bad/incomplete installation? I am using VS-2010 Pro.

Comment: That kind of property grid only works in the designer.  And only shows properties that make sense at design-time, note how the SafeFileName property is missing for example.

Answer (score 1):

Select an item and press alt-enter, or right click on the item and select properties. Or from the menu it is under view -> other windows.